# what's the meaning of the word "Json document" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json

I have read the usage of json in mysql documentation,but I still don't understand the meaning of the word "JSON document",does it mean "json data type" or anything else?I have searched the almost entire documentation for this word but however can't find any explanation about it.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON document is a string, which conforms to the JSON format.

Basically, if [JSON_VALID(*string*)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-valid) returns true, then it's a JSON document.

Example: In JSON format, you can make an array of strings, but the strings must individually be quoted, or else it's not valid JSON.

```
mysql> select JSON_VALID('[words, must, be, quoted]');
+-----------------------------------------+
| JSON_VALID('[words, must, be, quoted]') |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       0 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select JSON_VALID('["words", "must", "be", "quoted"]');
+-------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_VALID('["words", "must", "be", "quoted"]') |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               1 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

If it isn't valid JSON, then it isn't a "JSON document." If it isn't a JSON document, then a column of the [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) won't accept it, and none of [MySQL's JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) will work.

There are of course other syntax rules for JSON format. See https://www.json.org/ for a specification.

Comment: so actually a json document is a json-like string in mysql,is that true?

Comment: The term JSON document is not specific to MySQL. The term is used by other databases, and any other application that uses JSON. It generally means one valid JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Document is what it suggests a document in JSON format. Also check the Mongodb.com, they claim being a document based database. In fact what they mean, is that they transform objects into JSON data types. This is then called a document.

JSON documents can now be stored with the new JSON data type which is introduced to MySQL 8.0.  By the way it does not exist as such in the recent MariaDB, but you can still use some JSON-functions on some text-fields.

I hope this helps.